# XSLT sum function seems to lose decimal precision in result

Tags: xslt, sum

I'm facing a particular issue while executing XSLT `sum()` function.

I have a lot of invoice lines in my xml file, every single line contains an amount. I have to sum all of those amounts.

The following code is working, but I have a result that I do not understand.

```
sum(current-group()/cbc:LineExtensionAmount)
```

It seems that the `sum()` function has a bug while calculating a large total because I obtain a result with about 10 decimal precision, but I'm absolutely sure that I have no amounts that contain a value with 10 decimal precision.

For example I should see something like `140.586,86` but I get `140.586,8599999999` instead.

Why does this happen? I have looked for this issue in the web and I found that other people had the same problem. The main solution it seems to be the `round()` function. Due to legal restrictions I can not apply the `round()`.

What could I do to solve this? Note that I am using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400663/decimal-precision-in-xslt as that might help. You probably want to do `sum(current-group()/cbc:LineExtensionAmount/xs:decimal(.))` here, where the xs prefix is bound to namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`

Comment: @TimC your solution solved the problem. thank you so much for your help!